# Can not compile proto file in ubuntu for golang

Tags: go, protocol-buffers, grpc, protoc

I've installed these packages:

**google.golang.org/grpc**

**github.com/golang/protobuf/protoc-gen-go**

and exported path like this:

```
export PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/go/bin
```

when I try compile proto file with **protoc** command, I see command not found error:

```
protoc --go_out=. helloworld/helloworld.proto 

zsh: command not found: protoc
```

my project path is like: `/home/my-username/go/src/github.com/my-username/helloworld`

my go version: go1.12.5

and I use ubuntu 18.04

When I install it with binary file it works, but compiled go file does not contain some functions like: RegisterGreeterServer or NewGreeterClient

Comment: Do you install proto ?

Comment: @Зелёный yes installed it

Comment: Try to find `protoc` in the `/usr/bin` or `/usr/local/bin`.

Comment: there is no such file

Comment: hence the installation of `protobuf` is failed. Protobuf deliver `protoc`.

Comment: Show your `PATH` variable, looks like its messed somehow. `echo $PATH`

Comment: path: /home/my-username/.local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/snap/bin:/usr/local/go/bin

Comment: How you installed the `protobuf`? Show all steps.

Comment: I installed it using this: go get -u github.com/golang/protobuf/protoc-gen-go
by following https://github.com/golang/protobuf steps

Comment: That's a library not a `protobuf`.

Comment: @Зелёный how should I install protobuf for go?

Comment: For example https://gist.github.com/olivoil/a2e0e4f3427db8b6ef4a6374f9c4cb32

Comment: I tested it, but when it compiles proto file, compiled file does not contain some functions like: RegisterGreeterServer or NewGreeterClient

Comment: That other problem and not related to your question

Comment: protobuf-compiler package that introduced in the link that you mentioned, does not contain these functions when compiles! I know I should use protoc-gen-go package in golang but I don't know why it does not work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally with help of [Amit](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5980010/dave-amit), I installed protoc. but when I compiled proto file with this command

```
protoc --go_out=. add/add.proto
```

go compiled file did not contain some functions like: RegisterGreeterServer or NewGreeterClient for instance.

by [this reply](https://github.com/grpc/grpc-go/issues/1650#issuecomment-341929191) I found out issue and added `plugins=grpc`, then tried this command and it worked:

```
protoc --go_out=plugins=grpc:. add/add.proto
```

Answer (score 3):

`zsh: command not found: protoc` indicates that `protoc` is not installed on your machine. To do so, you need to download binary from [Official Releases](https://github.com/protocolbuffers/protobuf/releases), as you are on an `ubuntu` machine, I suggest you download [protoc-3.7.1-linux-x86_64.zip](https://github.com/protocolbuffers/protobuf/releases/download/v3.7.1/protoc-3.7.1-linux-x86_64.zip) (This is latest `protoc` at the time of writing this answer, you should check on the `releases` and download latest version)

You can download via browser or use following command:

`wget "https://github.com/protocolbuffers/protobuf/releases/download/v3.7.1/protoc-3.7.1-linux-x86_64.zip" -O protoc-3.7.1-linux-x86_64.zip`

Now unzip, you'll get two folders, "bin" and "include".

Copy `bin/protoc` to `/usr/local/bin/protoc` and `include/google` to `/usr/local/include/google`

This will properly install `protoc` on your machine.

To see if it got installed properly, try executing `protoc` command on your terminal. You should get something like following

[image]

If you still face any issues, please let me know.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thank you, it helped me.
I found out issue and posted my answer
https://stackoverflow.com/a/56293038/6173668

Comment: Just to add, the files that goes to include folder under `/usr/local/include` should be copied along with directory structure.

Answer (score 0):

I know its too late to discuss about it, but just in case it might be helpful for some one else, you can download protobuf for golang from github address [Github Repo](https://github.com/golang/protobuf)

and by navigating to {$LIB_PATH}/protobuf/protoc-gen-go and running "go build ." having a compiled binary from generator, and then add it to your path for feature usage